# Initialize a WPF combo box in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Is there a way to set the initial value of a databound `ComboBox` in XAML?

Here is my `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NHibernateTypes}}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=IdentifierPoperty, Path=PropertyType}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="0,5,10,0"/>
```

The `ItemsSource` is an `ObjectDataProvider` that gets values from an enum. I would like to have the the first value in the enum displayed in the combo box by default. I tried setting `SelectedIndex="0"`, but nothing happened.

Here's the really odd thing. I have a half dozen of these combo boxes in my window, all declared in the same manner as above. About half of them show the first value in their enum by default, but the others are blank. I have verified that all the bindings are working--each combo box shows the correct drop-down when I click it.

Is there a way to explicitly set a default index value for these combo boxes? Is there any reason some combo boxes would show a value by default while others do not? Thanks for your help.

David Veeneman

Foresight Systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer--I was using the object data provider incorrectly. I had created an ODP for each enum I needed to bind to a combo box, with the result that several combo boxes were bound to the same ODP. That's what was causing the problem. I changed my ODPs to provide one ODP for each combo box (some ODPs read the same enum) and that solved the problem. My combo boxes now initialize themselves properly.